# How to programmatically stop an executable war

Tags: jenkins, jetty, war

I have a problem with stopping an executable war file in the background as a service in Linux system. I can start the executable war with the following script:

```
    java -jar data.war&
```

but how do I stop it programmatically through Jenkins using SSH plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that is in need of the answer.

```
PROCESSID=`(ps aux | grep data| grep -v root | awk '{print $2}')`
kill -9 $PROCESSID
```

The above code kills the application with the name 'data' in the process list

Comment: Note that "kill -9" is equivalent to an immediate call to  `System.exit()`.  The JVM gets no opportunity to handle the situation.

Comment: I am pretty sure even JVM has method to handle the exit even on system level buried under sun package API as I have read somewhere

Comment: No. -9 means _now_!

Comment: did some research , proved that you are right. perhaps kill -SIGTERM is better here to let Java prog to handle the signal

Comment: Also I hope you do not have any other processes not run by root that has the string "data" somewhere in their output by "ps -aux".

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start with using the STOP port mechanism.  See this documentation for an example.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-running-jetty.html#quickstart-stopping-jetty

Comment: does not work for my case, the command proceeds to start the server and failed because duplicated server port.